# Superfish themable hooks not getting called

Tags: 7, navigation

According to superfish.module these following theme hooks are available.

```
 function theme_superfish($variables) {

    function theme_superfish_build($variables) {

    function theme_superfish_menu_item($variables) {

    function theme_superfish_menu_item_link($variables) {
```

but for some reason using these in my template.php only theme_superfish is getting called.

```
function nph_superfish($variables){
 dpm("nph_superfish");

        dpm($variables);

  return "HTML";
}
```

works

```
function nph_superfish_menu_item_link($variables) {
dpm("theme_superfish_menu_item_link");
      $menu_item = $variables['menu_item'];
      $link_options = $variables['link_options'];
      return l($menu_item['link']['title'], $menu_item['link']['href'], $link_options);
    }
```

doesn't work

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477629/how-to-add-a-span-tag-to-a-certain-custom-menu-link-in-drupal-7/22349886) is probably the most comprehensive to answer the question for what I am trying to achieve (I want to add classes to menu items based on the title).  Any ideas what might be happening?

UPDATE:

I just noticed a setting on the settings page, not mentioned in any of the answers I found around the web....

[image]

UPDATE: I've  just noticed it says Default:enabled ..., so by checking it I'm disabling it...

Answer (score 0):

As in my image [image]

Make sure these are checked or the theme hooks wont work, and they need to be checked even though, it says default:enabled.